# Where should i look for file from ajax call url [Magento]

Tags: ajax, magento

In ajax call i see this url being called via console.

`http://example.net/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/random-key/product/527/form_key/random-key/`

My question is where should i look for this ? I found `checkout/cart` on my template `app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/` and in `app/code/core/mage/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you got two perfectly good answers here is for extensive knowledge of Magento's URL

Note : http://www.example.com/[index.php]/ is your Magento url. Depending on your Magento config, you may or may not find index.php included in the URL.
{text} is a text that can vary, depending on the context.
[text] is a text which can or cannot appear, depending on the context.

```
http://www.example.com/[index.php]/{module_frontname}/{[controller]}/{[action]}/{[parameter_name_1]}/{[value_of_parameter_name_1]}/{[parameter_name_2]}/{[value_of_parameter_name_2]}/ (...) /{[parameter_name_n]}/{[value_of_parameter_name_n]}
```

So, appart from our base Magento URL, here are the parts and their meaning, and where you can find them.

**Part 1** : module_frontname : the "*front name*" of a module. This value can be found in `app/code/{codePool}/{NamespaceOfModule}/{ModuleName}/etc/config.xml`.
In those file, you will find one or more `<frontName>` nodes, defining the module front name.

***In your case***, this is a core module, 'Mage_Checkout' so it is in the codePool core. (If you want to know more about codePool, I can write more about it but let's stick it to sample things here).
If you look at the file `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/etc/config.xml` you will indeed find those lines of code

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mage_Checkout</module>
                <frontName>checkout</frontName>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

Which define that all the request done to this Magento with `http://www.example.com/[index.php]/checkout/` will be handled by the module Mage_Checkout and its controllers.

**Part 2** : controller. Controllers are easy to spot on Magento. They are located on the folder and sub folders of `app/code/{codePool}/{NamespaceOfModule}/{ModuleName}/controllers/` The name of the file and the class in the file there correspond to the controller part of the URL. So if you find this url `http://www.example.com/[index.php]/module_frontname/controller/` the controller file will be named ControllerController.php and the class name `NamespaceOfModule_ModuleName_ControllerController`. So the part of the url will have the first letter in upper case and will be suffixed by Controller. 
 `http://www.example.com/[index.php]/module_frontname/something/` -> SomethingController.php / `NamespaceOfModule_ModuleName_SomethingController`
`http://www.example.com/[index.php]/module_frontname/else/` -> ElseController.php / `NamespaceOfModule_ModuleName_ElseController`.

*Please note* : That there is a controller per default. This controller is the controller IndexController. So if you find an url like `http://www.example.com/[index.php]/module_frontname/` that means it is implicitly call the controller IndexController, that is why this part was set as optional in my first url example.

***In your case*** : you will indeed find a file in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controller/CartController.php` with the class `Mage_Core_CartController`.

**Part 3** : action. This one is easy to spot too. In a given controller class, the action is a function which is suffixed by "Action".
This part is sensible to case so please mind that aCtionAction will handle the url `http://www.example.com/[index.php]/module_frontname/controller/aCtion/` (please note he capital C of aCtion.
So this URL `http://www.example.com/[index.php]/module_frontname/controller/action/` will call the function named actionAction in the controller controllerController. 
The same way : `http://www.example.com/[index.php]/module_frontname/controller/some/` -> will be handled by the function someAction.

*Please note* : the same default behaviour apply to action than to controller. The default action in then indexAction(). So indeed when you call `http://www.example.com/[index.php]/module_frontname/` you are reaching the controller IndexController but also its indexAction. And if you call the url `http://www.example.com/[index.php]/module_frontname/controller` you will reach the indexAction of the controller controllerController. 
*Please also note* : that the order and meaning of the 3 first parts will never, ever change.
So if you want to call a specific action of the default controller IndexController, you have then to specify the controller in your url like that `http://www.example.com/[index.php]/module_frontname/index/some` because if you try to reach it that way `http://www.example.com/[index.php]/module_frontname/some` you will get the action indexAction of the controller SomeController and not the action someAction of the controller IndexController !

***In you case*** : if you open up the file `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controller/CartController.php` you will indeed find a function addAction around the line 191.

```
public function addAction()
{
  // (... lots of code come here which I'm not going to reproduce)
}
```

**Part 4 to n** : Those are basically get parameters at Zend Framework sauce.
`http://www.example.com/[index.php]/module_frontname/controller/action/param1/value1` is strictly equals to `http://www.example.com/[index.php]/module_frontname/controller/action?param1=value1`. The same way `http://www.example.com/[index.php]/module_frontname/controller/action/param1/value1/param2/value2` is equals to `http://www.example.com/[index.php]/module_frontname/controller/action?param1=value1&param2=value2`. This will always go by pair parameter_name / parameter_value

*Please note* : That the explanation in the second note regarding the default action / controller apply also here. So if you want to have a parameter in you action indexAction in the controller IndexController, you then have to write the url in full `http://www.example.com/[index.php]/module_frontname/index/index/param1/value1` because this url `http://www.example.com/[index.php]/module_frontname/param1/value1` will match the controller Param1Controller and the action value1Action and not the controller IndexController and the action indexAction with the requested parameters !

***In your case*** : uenc/random-key/product/527/form_key/random-key/
means you have that

```
$_GET['uenc'] == 'random-key'
$_GET['product'] == '527'
$_GET['form_key'] == 'random-key'
```

And indeed in the file stated above, you will find in the function cartAction() those lines of code :

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
try {
    if (isset($params['qty'])) {
        // (... lots of code come here which I'm not going to reproduce)
    } 
} catch(Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    // (... lots of code come here which I'm not going to reproduce)
}
// (... lots of code come here which I'm not going to reproduce)
```

***In your case*** (that is the last one, I promise) : your assumption was nearly exact trying to find a template. But sadly for you this in not a visual action, so it will not display anything, just handle a request to add a product to the cart and then redirect to another url like the last lines of the cartAction state around line 251

```
$url = $this->_getSession()->getRedirectUrl(true);
if ($url) {
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
} else {
    $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
}
```

In hope that this complete Magento URL explanation will help someone :)

Answer (score 1):

This should be `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php`, `addAction` method.

Answer (score 1):

http://example.net/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/random-key/product/527/form_key/random-key/

you can find this in Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
in given file you will find addAction()

So your url will be like 
**checkout** - Module name
**cart** - controller name
**add** - function name and others are parameters.

Answer (score 1):

`http://example.net/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/random-key/product/527/form_key/random-key/`

checkout : Module Name (Find module with this name)

cart : Cart Controller (Inside the target module look for Controllers folder > CartController.php file)

add : add action method (And inside the controller class above look for addAction() Method)